# Idea of Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

How do I find out if a number is sum of 2 palindromes?

Example:

**123** = **101 + 22**.

See **101** and **22** are palindromes;

Comment: Do you accept $121 = 0 + 121$?

Answer (score 1):

The first, naive way of thinkin is to simply say "check all palindromes to see if they sum to your number"

You can then improve this in two ways:

- First, you don't have to check pairs of palindromes. You can simply check each palindrome, subtract it from your number and se if it results in a palindrome.
- Second, see how you can generate palindromes. For example, you can generate all palindroms of length $2n$ by going throuh all numbers of length $n$ and reversin them, and a similar procedure holds for length $2n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I told my friend Ruby:

```
def is_sum_of_two_palindromes?(n)
  i_max = n / 2
  (1..i_max).each do |i|
    j = n - i
    if (is_palindrome?(i) and is_palindrome?(j))
      puts "n = #{i} + #{j}"
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end

def is_palindrome?(n)
  s = n.to_s
  s == s.reverse
end
```

When I asked her

```
is_sum_of_two_palindromes?(123)
```

she responded with

```
n = 2 + 121
```

That was kind of boring, so I told her

```
def is_sum_of_two_non_trivial_palindromes?(n)
  i_max = n / 2
  (1..i_max).each do |i|
    j = n - i
    if (is_non_trivial_palindrome?(i) and is_non_trivial_palindrome?(j))
      puts "n = #{i} + #{j}"
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end

def is_non_trivial_palindrome?(n)
  s = n.to_s
  s.length > 1 and s == s.reverse
end
```

and asked

```
is_sum_of_two_non_trivial_palindromes?(123)
```

where Ruby replied

```
n = 22 + 101
```